# How to install kingsoft office in ubuntu 14.04 64 bit?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, wps-office

I install ubuntu 14.04 last night, every is fine except the trouble in installing kingsoft office which is widely used in China, I googled a lot, nothing happened. Has someone succeeded in using it?

Comment: To install the 64 bit read this :

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-kingsoft-wps-office-alpha-16-on-ubuntu-debian-and-derivative-systems/

Answer (score 4):

What have you tried so far? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS x86_64 and it works perfectly fine for me. Try getting the .deb from http://wps-community.org/download.html.

The dependencies are:

```
Depends: libc6(>= 2.12), libstdc++6(>= 4.5), libfreetype6(>= 2.4), libglu1-mesa, libcups2, libglib2.0-0, libpng12-0, libsm6, libxrender1, libfontconfig1
```

which can be viewed with `dpkg -I kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4280~a12p4_i386.deb` or `apt-cache  .

You might have to do `dpkg --add-architecture i386` and `apt-get update` before you can install i386 multiarch packages such as `sudo apt-get install libcups2:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libpng12-0:i386` ...etc (:i386 because the dependencies are i386 just like the package)

```
sudo dpkg -i kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4280~a12p4_i386.deb
```

should work after that.

Comment: Did this work for folks?  I am getting an error indicating that the wps .deb file is not, in fact, and debian archive.